# Attempt to attack mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is it an attack and what is the result ?

```
120406 15:47:32 44330 Connect   Access denied for user 'sdgfsdgfsdgfs'@'89.107.230.194' (using password: YES)  
44330 Connect   sdgfsdgfsdgfs@89.107.230.194 as  on
```

How to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hack attempt, they were unable to connect.

I suggest you install a firewall to solve numerous issues and prevent this from occurring in the future.

Comment: I have a firewall ! my mysql log is full of such messages !

Comment: If you ahve a firewall, I suggest you block everything that is not needed. Looks like you have mysql at least open to the world.

Answer (score 0):

You should really disable remote MySQL access, set to only allow local inbound connections. [Use a tunneling script](http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/Where_can_i_get_the_HTTP_tunnel_script_file?) if you really need to connect from elsewhere.

The verdict in those two lines of log is Access Denied. But you can search the whole file for access grants.

Comment: I cannot disable because it is a part of an application.

Comment: in that case please read http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/06/security-flaw-in-mysql-mariadb-allows-access-with-any-password-just-keep-submitting-it/ and make sure this doesn't affect you. People could be trying to own your server.